# Pose from point and two vectors

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have point p, normal n and vector v, which is orthogonal to n. I want to compute the gripper Pose perpendicular with the normal and rotated based on v. In other words the resulting frame should have z axis perpendicular to n and x or y perpendicular to v. How can I compute the orientation quaternion?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52173/pose-from-point-and-two-vectors/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understand you correctly you want an orientation/a new coordinate frame that is perpendicular to n, and "directed with v" (but v is not necessarily perpendicular to n).

The easiest might be to create a rotation matrix. n is one entry. A second one can be derived by n cross v. This should make sure that this entry is perpendicular to n and directed from v. The third one should be the cross of the other two.

My guess is that n cross v should go to column 1 and n to column 2, but not guarantees.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2013-01-14**:
The v is actually orthogonal to n, I have edited the question.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-01-14**:
This should make it easier. If I'm not mistaken, just take n, v, n cross v to build the rotation matrix.